# F string list comprehensions example needed

Tags: python, list-comprehension, f-string

I have a list of floats that I would like to print using an f-string:
Here is the list

```
er=[0.3401126304419511,
 0.32561695086083536,
 0.3115512789515306,
 0.21734184387097139,
 0.22354269408531188]
```

and I want to print them using an f-string as follows:

```
print(f'{err}')
```

which produces:

```
[0.3401126304419511, 0.32561695086083536, 0.3115512789515306, 0.21734184387097139, 0.22354269408531188]
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
print(f'{err:.2}')
```

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "C:\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   
    File "<ipython-input-166-bbcdc82a9939>", line 1, in <module>
        print(f'{err:.2}') 
    TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

Is this a bug or a feature? How do I make this work?

I'm using python version:

`Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: `[f'{el:.2}' for el in er]`?

Comment: What is the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Format specifiers like `:.2` are not automatically distributed over the elements of a list.

Comment: in ```numpy``` world it works ```print(f'{np.around(er_np,2)}')``` (```er_np=np.array(er)```)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it using a list comprehension :

```
print([f"{x:.2}" for x in er])
```

Comment: maybe this doesn't work in some versions of python 3?
`$ python3 --version`  
`Python 3.5.2`  
`$ python3 -c 'a=list(range(3));print(a)'`  
`[0, 1, 2]`  
`$ python3 -c 'a=list(range(3));print(a);print([f"{b}_str" for b in a])'`  
`File "<string>", line 1`  
`a=list(range(3));print(a);print([f"{b}_str" for b in a])`  
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @dlamblin fstrings were added in Python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Since, you wish to print the first 2 digits after the decimal of each individual elements. You will have to iterate over it & print them out as -

```
[f'{element:.2}' for element in er]
```

Usually we can apply aggregation type functions like `len, sum`directly on a list without needing to iterate over it.

Comment: Is this not available in python 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

Here, `print(f'{er}')` is equivalent to `print(er)`. It will output the representation of your list which is as you stated:

```py
[0.3401126304419511, 0.32561695086083536, 0.3115512789515306, 0.21734184387097139, 0.22354269408531188]
```

When you want to apply `f'{err:.2}'`, what you actually want is to apply this format rule on every element of the list. You will need a for loop or a list comprehension to achieve this.

As suggested in the comments by @Buckeye14Guy, the following should work as expected:

```py
er2 = [f'{el:.2}' for el in er]
print(er2)
```

Other approach could also work (map) but I guess you have enough to keep it going now.